# implement switch in compiler (x86-64)

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction

I'm implementing a switch construct with a jump table. (Windows x86-64)

Everything is set up, but it freezes. I think I did not quite understand how an indirect jump works.

I set up a jump table (before the instructions). With 64 bit entries of relative "distances" I would like to jump. For example:

`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

(two values, 0 and +18, with correct endianess)

The jump instruction I currently have implemented:

`FF 25 A2 FF FF FF`

Which translates (with a disassembler):

`jmp QWORD PTR [rip+0xffffffffffffffa2]`

Which reads the first value in the jump table (offset should be correct), which is zero.
So, shouldn't this be added to the RIP and make a jump of nothing, i. e. continue at next line?

Comment: Indirect `jmp` reads the absolute address to jump to, not a relative one. Otherwise, its mnemonic would read `jmp rip+[rip+0xsomething]`. Your code sets `rip` to zero.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'm confused though, because `rip` is short for _relative_ instruction pointer. So I thought it's relative, but I guess it's not. Is there a way to do a relative jump (so I don't have to relocate the jump table)?

Comment: @DanyBittel `rip` is `ip` plus the same `r` prefix all 64 bit general purpose instructions have. Nothing “relative.”

Comment: What you could do is to calculate the target address; perhaps [`lea rax, [rip]`](/questions/12397451/why-cant-i-save-the-value-of-rip) followed by `add rax, [your_table_entry]` and then `jmp rax`. You'll gave to adjust your entries to cope with the fact that you also have to jump over the add and the jmp that follow the lea.

Comment: Thanks alot @Rhymoid, I was figuring out something similar, but would have stumbled over getting rip, which you foresight fully linked.

Comment: that `rip`is only really the eip register, clears a up a lot of other confusions I had. Thanks @FUZZxxl